# Earth Engine ImageCollection filter alternative temoporal bands

Tags: modis, google-earth-engine

As my question in [Remove alternate features from ImageCollection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/262344/remove-alternate-features-from-imagecollection?noredirect=1#comment416148_262344) was put on hold, I am clarifying the question here.

I am using google earth engine for some analysis. I can import MODIS vegetation indices data at 16-day intervals and Land Surface Temperature/Emissivity at 8 day interval.

These data are imported as earthengine ImageCollection.

Is there a way on how to filter out only those images in LST imagecollection which correspond to dates in vegetation indices data. In another way, How can I filter the LST imagecollection to get 16 day ImageCollection?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/e11a0eee44c19a8690d02e4fc9d22b5e

Comment: It is always best to update and edit your original question and vote to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this would be just one workaround:

```js
var lst = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/MYD11A2").sort("system:time_start");

// Use an iterating function passing as first argument a list
// containing: [empty list, switch value]

var filtered = lst.iterate(function(img, it_var){

  // cast and get iteration values
  var newcol = ee.List(ee.List(it_var).get(0))
  var swich = ee.Number(ee.List(it_var).get(1))

  // change swich
  swich = ee.Number(ee.Algorithms.If(swich, 0, 1))

  // get the img only if swich is 0
  var filter = ee.List(ee.Algorithms.If(swich, newcol, newcol.add(img)))

  // cast and return
  return ee.List([filter, swich])

}, ee.List([ee.List([]), 1]))

// cast result
var result = ee.List(filtered)

// get acual ImageCollection from result
var filtered_col = ee.ImageCollection(result.get(0))

// print results
print(filtered_col)
```

and remember when you ask to include actual code in the question, and not just a link (as an EE user I understand the reason, but this is Stack Exchange and there are rules and conventions)

Comment: Thanks, I am new to EE so thought that EE users like the code in EE code-editor.

Comment: Yes, it's fine, you should include both. Did the code work as you expected?